# Enabling and Disabling Cache : Retrofit ,Okhttp Implementation

Tags: android, caching, http-headers, retrofit, okhttp

I have an Implementation of Retrofit with OkHTTP as a client configured with an Interceptor to enable Cache Feature. Well the cache Works fine , But I have trouble disabling Cache using the Mechanisms I already have. I do have a solution for this : Not using the Code Containing cache mechanism and use a normal retrofit implementation each time I want to disable Cache.

Here Is the Full Code . [Service Generator](https://futurestud.io/blog/retrofit-getting-started-and-android-client/%22Service%20Generator%22) to turn a retrofit Interface to a reusable client. and Request  A Request/response Interceptor

```
package com.example.infinite.adapter;

import android.content.Context;
import android.util.Log;

import com.example.infinite.settings.Config;
import com.example.infinite.utils.ConnectionDetector;
import com.example.infinite.utils.SharedPreferenceEasy;
import com.squareup.okhttp.Cache;
import com.squareup.okhttp.Interceptor;
import com.squareup.okhttp.OkHttpClient;
import com.squareup.okhttp.Request;
import com.squareup.okhttp.Response;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.concurrent.Executor;
import java.util.concurrent.Executors;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

import retrofit.RequestInterceptor;
import retrofit.RestAdapter;
import retrofit.android.MainThreadExecutor;
import retrofit.client.OkClient;

/**
 * Created by user on 5/18/2015.
 * Create REST  Adapter for Given Class
 */
public class ServiceGenerator {

    protected static RestAdapter mRestAdapter;
    static String secret = "Schhh!!";
    private static Context mContext;
    private static final Interceptor mCacheControlInterceptor = new Interceptor() {
        @Override
        public Response intercept(Chain chain) throws IOException {
            Request request = chain.request();

            // Add Cache Control only for GET methods
            if (request.method().equals("GET")) {
                //see if cache is enabled
                if (enableCache) {
                    if (new ConnectionDetector(mContext).isConnectingToInternet()) {
                        // 1 day
                        request.newBuilder()
                                .header("Cache-control", "only-if-cached")
                                .header("Accept", "application/json")
                                .header("Authorization", "Basic " + secret)
                                .build();
                        Log.d("REQUEST CACHE", "Only-if-Cached");
                    } else {
                        // upto 4 weeks stale
                        request.newBuilder()
                                .header("Cache-control", "public, max-stale=2419200")
                                .header("Accept", "application/json")
                                .header("Authorization", "Basic " + secret)
                                .build();
                        Log.d("REQUEST CACHE", "MAX STALE ");
                    }
                }else
                {
                    //NO CACHE
                    request.newBuilder()
                            .header("Cache-control" ,"public,max-age=0")
                            .header("Accept", "application/json")
                            .header("Authorization", "Basic " + secret)
                            .build();
                    Log.d("REQUEST CACHE","NO CACHE ");
                }
            }

            //s-maxage for requests with authentications
            Response response = chain.proceed(request);

            // Re-write response CC header to force use of cache &  set header such that it is cached.
            if(enableCache) {
                Log.d("RESPONSE CACHE","MAXAGE-CACHE ");
                return response.newBuilder()
                        .header("Cache-control", "public, max-age=86400") // 1 day
                        .header("Accept", "application/json")
                        //Authentication Header , do you want to see it in the response
                        .header("Authorization", "Basic " + secret)
                        .build();
            }else{
                Log.d("RESPONSE CACHE","NO-CACHE ");
                //Say that you don't want the result to be storedcontinue
                return  response.newBuilder()
                        .header("Cache-control", " public,max-age=0, no-cache, no-store,must-revalidate")
                        .header("Pragma","no-cache")
                        .build();
            }
        }
    };


    /**
     * @param serviceClass Service class To create the adaptor for
     * @param baseUrl      Base URL of the API
     * @param context      Used to create a Cache
     * @param <S>
     * @return Rest Adapter
     */
    public static <S> S createService(Class<S> serviceClass, String baseUrl, Context context) {


        mContext = context;
        enableCache = new SharedPreferenceEasy(context).RetreiveBoolean(Config.KEY_PREF_NETWK_CACHE,true);

        // Create Cache
        Cache cache = null;
        cache = new Cache(new File(mContext.getCacheDir(), "http"), SIZE_OF_CACHE);

        // Create OkHttpClient
        OkHttpClient okHttpClient = new OkHttpClient();
        if(enableCache) {
            okHttpClient.setCache(cache);
        }
        okHttpClient.setConnectTimeout(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        okHttpClient.setReadTimeout(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

        // Add Cache-Control Interceptor
        okHttpClient.networkInterceptors().add(mCacheControlInterceptor);

        // Create Executor
        Executor executor = Executors.newCachedThreadPool();

        RestAdapter.Builder builder = new RestAdapter.Builder()
                .setEndpoint(baseUrl)
                .setExecutors(executor, new MainThreadExecutor())
                .setClient(new OkClient(okHttpClient))
                .setLogLevel(RestAdapter.LogLevel.FULL);

        RestAdapter adapter = builder.build();


        return adapter.create(serviceClass);
    }

}
```

I want to acheive a compulsive  request from Network when cache is disabled from my app's settings. if(enableCache)